# Resources for Testing Applications with Bonita as a Backend

Tags: testing, web, workflow

We are developing some web apps with Bonita as the workflow management tool. Are there any resources that any of you may know of which would assist me in developing test automa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Selenium.  (Download from http://seleniumhq.org)

You can use firefox to create the tests (it's a bit like creating macros).  Then you can re-run them later or use the test server to automate a large series of tests.

Below I've included the source to a basic test to log into the Bonita User Experience and kick off a process.

Replace SERVERIPADDRESS, MYUSERNAME and MYPASSWORD with your details.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://SERVERIPADDRESS:8080/bonita/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Business Process Management</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=username</td>
    <td>MYUSERNAME</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>typeAndWait</td>
    <td>name=password</td>
    <td>MYPASSWORD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=div.gwt-Label</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=div.menu_choice</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.bonita_form_button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```